# My prefix may be your end

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> The answer makes it harder for me to know if the riddle is correct.
>
> My prefix may be your end
>
> My suffix is a question
>
> Sadly my infix can´t be together with my prefix or suffix (normally) :(

Hint 1:

> My suffix is short and mostly asked by young people

Hint 2:

> If we don't care the prefix may be our all end

Hint 3:

> One of my edits may be a big hint on my small infix

Hint 4:

> Don't worry there are so many specialist fighting against my prefix

Comment: I think this needs more hints.

Comment: @Sid done now 2 should be obvious ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

is it

> Germany,

My guess for the prefix:

> Germ, an epidemic can kill all people, there are scientist who research the cure

The infix:

> an, pointed out by Wazzabii

The suffix:

> y, pointed out by Alan hoover

But I still dont know why it is hard for you to know the answer is correct,

> Is it because you are from Germany (from your profile)? or is it because "Ger Many" in my language it spells like "there many"?

Comment: Congratulations it's because I'm from Germany and no native speaker. Things like an/a are harder for me to understand and it makes riddling very hard.

Comment: oh.. I see.. nice riddle!

Comment: I guess the first line is meta in a way.

Comment: @noedne I wanted it as a clue but sure someone could say its meta.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do this to get something rolling on this puzzle.

Answer:

> Butterfly

The answer makes it hard for me to know if the riddle is correct.

> ?

My prefix may be your end

> Butt  - end, self explanatory

My suffix is a question

Hint 1:

My suffix is short and mostly asked by young people

> Y sounds like why - commonly asked by little kids

Sadly my infix can´t be together with my prefix or suffix (normally) :(

> butterfl, erfly - neither one of those really work as words.

Comment: You're close, one answer was completly right.

Answer (score 2):

Let try this:

> botany

The answer makes it hard for me to know if the riddle is correct.

> I don't know what to think about this

My prefix may be your end

> "Bot" There are many occasions in Films or other Media where Bots or artificial intelligence ends all life.

My suffix is a question

> As Alan Hover said in his answer, the Y sounds like "Why?"

Sadly my infix can't be together with my prefix or suffix (normally) :(

> "an" is only(mostly) used when the following word starts with a vowel, which is not the case in "bot" or "why/y"

Comment: Wow 2 are right so close ;)

Comment: I suspect you are correct with the prefix, since it fits the second clue so well.

Comment: To help, infix and suffix are right ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer may be

> Miscellany

The answer makes it hard for me to know if the riddle is correct.

> A miscellany is a collection of different items, a mixture.

My prefix may be your end

> Miscell sounds like *missile* which could be my end, indeed may be all our ends if nuclear war should occur (as suggested in Hint 2).

My suffix is a question

> As pointed out by Alan Hoover, 'y' sounds like why?

Sadly my infix can´t be together with my prefix or suffix (normally) :(

> As pointed out by JonMark Perry, the word 'an' is normally followed by a word beginning with a vowel.

Comment: Stil just the prefix is wrong, gave another hint now it should be easy.